# Trying to make a method pause using coroutines, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]

 public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
 {
     //storage for the object's rigidbody
     public Rigidbody2D rb2D;
     //the public modifier for speed so i can edit from outside
     public float speed;
     //reliably take movements each second in an even, reliable manner. 
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         //i move left and right if  i use "a" or "d or "left" or "right" 
         float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         //I move up and down if i use "w" or "s" or "up" or "down"
         float moveY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
         //Vector inputs the move directions into a vector2 so i can move
         Vector2 move = new Vector2(moveX, moveY);
         rb2D.velocity = move * speed;
     }
     //following two methods are for the respective spikey builds
     public void slow()
     {
         print("Shit, spike's got me!");
         speed = .3f;
         StartCoroutine(PauseTheSlowdown(2.1f));
         speed = 1;
     }
     public void Bigslow()
     {
         print("HOLY CRAP THAT HURT");
         speed = 0f;
         StartCoroutine(PauseTheSlowdown(3.7f));
         speed = 1;
     }

     IEnumerator PauseTheSlowdown(float seconds)
     {
         print("Pause this crap");
         yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(seconds);
     }

 }
```

I've encountered a bit of an issue here where my code seems to be perfectly fine. It runs, and then when an external script goes to pull from either of the spike methods, it behaves like the coroutine isn't even there and goes right from slow-down back to full speed. 
There are no errors or issues other than the coroutine simply does not cause a wait to happen. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't put the code that has to pause in a normal function. You have to put it inside the coroutine function.

For example, in your `Bigslow` function, `Speed` variable will be set to `0`. The `PauseTheSlowdown` coroutine will be started. Unity will wait one frame only in the `PauseTheSlowdown` function then return to the `Bigslow` where speed is set to `1`. It will not wait because you are starting it from a `void` function.

You have two options:

**1**.Make your `slow` and `Bigslow` functions to be `IEnumerator` instead `void` then yield when `StartCoroutine` is called.

```
public IEnumerator slow()
{
    print("Shit, spike's got me!");
    speed = .3f;
    yield return StartCoroutine(PauseTheSlowdown(2.1f));
    speed = 1;
}

public IEnumerator Bigslow()
{
    print("HOLY CRAP THAT HURT");
    speed = 0f;
    yield return StartCoroutine(PauseTheSlowdown(3.7f));
    speed = 1;
}

IEnumerator PauseTheSlowdown(float seconds)
{
    print("Pause this crap");
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(seconds);
}
```

Notice the `yield return` before calling `StartCoroutine`.

**2**.Move the code you want to execute and wait for some time to the `PauseTheSlowdown` coroutine function:

```
public void slow()
{
    print("Shit, spike's got me!");
    StartCoroutine(PauseTheSlowdown(2.1f, .3f, 1));
}
public void Bigslow()
{
    print("HOLY CRAP THAT HURT");
    StartCoroutine(PauseTheSlowdown(3.7f, 0f, 1));
}

IEnumerator PauseTheSlowdown(float seconds, float before, float after)
{
    print("Pause this crap");
    speed = before;
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(seconds);
    speed = after;
}
```

Comment: This answers a lot of questions, thank you. I'll give it a try right away.